# Enabling single left-click for Expo in Compiz

Tags: compiz

I've got my 12.04 almost running exactly how I want but I have a small issue with the Expo plugin in CCSM.

I'd like to use my left button to single click out of Expo instead of double clicking. I realise that I can single right click but I'd prefer to have my left button do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

- Compiz Config Settings Manager -> Desktop -> Expo
- Change Exit Expo to disabled
- Change Drag & Drop to Button 3
- Change Exit Expo to enabled, Button 1
- You will receive a warning message. Dismiss it.

You're done. Left-click will now select the workspace, right-click will allow you to drag and drop windows between workspaces.

"Exit Expo" is confusingly named. It should really be called "Select workspace". Selecting the workspace does indeed exit the Expo program, but it's hardly the most important aspect of the action.